# Show text underneath image while hovering without disrupting other elements

Tags: html, css

So I am creating a menu for a new site and I'm doing my best to make it mobile responsive. Each of the items in the menu has an icon and a name. When the screen is full width, both are displayed, with the text located underneath the icon.

I have set it up so that when a user rolls over a link, the text changes colour and the background image of the icon also changes.

When the screen grows smaller, the text disappears leaving just the icons. Currently when a user rolls over one of the icons while in this mode, the text will appear below, but it will also move the elements around it and shift the icon upwards. I want to be able to have the icons remain in the same position when rolled over, and have the text appear below without changing the width or disrupting the other images.

I have done a small mockup of how I would like it to look, along with my current solution [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moloP.png).

The system uses Foundation but I am not able to edit any of the js, and I can only work within my css file and this HTML portion for the menu. There are two elements on either side of the menu which aren't pictured.

This is a cut portion of my menu HTML.

```
<div id="icon-menu" class="medium-9 columns">
    <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="/home">
            <div id="nav-home"></div>
            <span>Home</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-item">
        <a href="/my-learning">
            <div id="nav-my-learning"></div>
            <span>My Learning</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my css, with one rollover example:

```
#logo img{
    max-width: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}

#icon-menu{
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-item{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 15px;
}

.menu-item a{
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    color: #606060;
}

.menu-item a:hover{
    color: #803589;
    font-weight:400;
}

.menu-item div{
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
    .menu-item span{
        display: none;
    }

    .menu-item div{
        height:50px;
    }

    .menu-item a:hover span{
        display: initial;
        position: relative;
    }

    .menu-item a:hover div{
        height: 30px;
    }
}

/*------Styling the Menu Hovers------*/

#nav-home{
    background-image: url("/site/img/icon_home.png");
}

.menu-item a[href="/home"]:hover #nav-home{
    background-image: url("/site/img/icon_home_purple.png");
}
```

You can view the full version of my code over at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a5rso6xy/).

All help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cameronjonesweb/a5rso6xy/2/

Here's what I did

Set `.menu-item` to `position:relative`

Inside your media query set your `.menu-item span` to this

```
.menu-item span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

This takes the span out of the object flow and centres it below the icon.

Remove that height from `.menu-item div`

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, thank you! If I want to add more space between the words and the icons, is it best to just increase the top value, or is there a better way?

Comment: @TessaMary yes increasing the top value for the span is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

On the text that you wish not to *wrap* and cause the element to get taller:

```
max-width: <yourWidth>;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

This will prevent the text from wrapping, but it will also make the parts that would wrap, unreadable; this is probably not an optimal solution.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ke8yvLs/)

A better solution would be to make sure the elements are wide enough to hold the largest string of text you'll be using, which you can adjust dynamically with some `@media` queries that will stack horizontally or vertically depending on viewport width.